# How do I calculate the Max 15-min TWA in R?

Tags: r, rolling-computation, weighted-average

I have a dataset that contains the ppm of a chemical measured every 20 seconds for 4.5 hours.  A simplified, shortened version of the dataset looks like this:

```
df<-data.frame('ppm'=c(rep(20, 90)),
               'date.time'= c("2023-01-13 15:00:00", "2023-01-13 15:00:20", "2023-01-13 15:00:40", "2023-01-13 15:01:00", "2023-01-13 15:01:20", "2023-01-13 15:01:40",
                              "2023-01-13 15:02:00", "2023-01-13 15:02:20", "2023-01-13 15:02:40", "2023-01-13 15:03:00", "2023-01-13 15:03:20", "2023-01-13 15:03:40",
                              "2023-01-13 15:04:00", "2023-01-13 15:04:20", "2023-01-13 15:04:40", "2023-01-13 15:05:00", "2023-01-13 15:05:20", "2023-01-13 15:05:40",
                              "2023-01-13 15:06:00", "2023-01-13 15:06:20", "2023-01-13 15:06:40", "2023-01-13 15:07:00", "2023-01-13 15:07:20", "2023-01-13 15:07:40",
                              "2023-01-13 15:08:00", "2023-01-13 15:08:20", "2023-01-13 15:08:40", "2023-01-13 15:09:00", "2023-01-13 15:09:20", "2023-01-13 15:09:40",
                              "2023-01-13 15:10:00", "2023-01-13 15:10:20", "2023-01-13 15:10:40", "2023-01-13 15:11:00", "2023-01-13 15:11:20", "2023-01-13 15:11:40",
                              "2023-01-13 15:12:00", "2023-01-13 15:12:20", "2023-01-13 15:12:40", "2023-01-13 15:13:00", "2023-01-13 15:13:20", "2023-01-13 15:13:40",
                              "2023-01-13 15:14:00", "2023-01-13 15:14:20", "2023-01-13 15:14:40", "2023-01-13 15:15:00", "2023-01-13 15:15:20", "2023-01-13 15:15:40",
                              "2023-01-13 15:16:00", "2023-01-13 15:16:20", "2023-01-13 15:16:40", "2023-01-13 15:17:00", "2023-01-13 15:17:20", "2023-01-13 15:17:40",
                              "2023-01-13 15:18:00", "2023-01-13 15:18:20", "2023-01-13 15:18:40", "2023-01-13 15:19:00", "2023-01-13 15:19:20", "2023-01-13 15:19:40",
                              "2023-01-13 15:20:00", "2023-01-13 15:20:20", "2023-01-13 15:20:40", "2023-01-13 15:21:00", "2023-01-13 15:21:20", "2023-01-13 15:21:40",
                              "2023-01-13 15:22:00", "2023-01-13 15:22:20", "2023-01-13 15:22:40", "2023-01-13 15:23:00", "2023-01-13 15:23:20", "2023-01-13 15:23:40",
                              "2023-01-13 15:24:00", "2023-01-13 15:24:20", "2023-01-13 15:24:40", "2023-01-13 15:25:00", "2023-01-13 15:25:20", "2023-01-13 15:25:40",
                              "2023-01-13 15:26:00", "2023-01-13 15:26:20", "2023-01-13 15:26:40", "2023-01-13 15:27:00", "2023-01-13 15:27:20", "2023-01-13 15:27:40",
                              "2023-01-13 15:28:00", "2023-01-13 15:28:20", "2023-01-13 15:28:40", "2023-01-13 15:29:00", "2023-01-13 15:29:20", "2023-01-13 15:29:40"))
```

How can I add a column that calculates the rolling 15min TWA (Time Weighted Average)?  I know the last step would be taking the max of this new column.

I imagine the `tibbletime::rollify()` or `zoo::rollapply()` functions could work?

Comment: Look at `slider::slide_period` (and I assume your real data has a `'date.time'` field that is not strings?)

Comment: Yes, it is a real date.time field.  I will take a look at `slider::slide_period`, thank you!

Comment: (I only ask because `slider::slide_period` requires that its time (`.i`) argument class be one of `Date` or `POSIXt`, which your sample data is clearly not.)

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved my own problem with this:

```
TWA<-max(rollapply(df$ppm, width=45, mean, by.column=FALSE))
TWA
```

If I need to add a new column, I could have done this:

```
df$TWA<-c(rep(NA, 44), rollapply(df$ppm, width=45, mean, by.column=FALSE))
```

Comment: I'm glad this works for you ... realize that if/when you have data that is not perfectly spaces, this fails _logically_ and silently. The benefit of `slider::slide_period` is that it takes into account possibly variant time-between-observations.